# Django inexplicable routing issue?

Tags: django

I am building a simple news app with posts and I have a seemingly inexplicable error on a routing a request. The URL and the route match perfectly and yet, Django complains about not finding a match, which  obviously matches.

```
The current path, blog/tag/international/, didn't match any of these.
```

My urls.py are...

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# App name
app_name = 'blog'

# Url Patterns
urlpatterns = [
    # Default lists all posts
    url('^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),

    # List post by tag
    url('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),

    # Post
    url('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),

]
```

Please help, what am I missing? Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the path method for that url route.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# App name
app_name = 'blog'

# Url Patterns
urlpatterns = [
    # Default lists all posts
    url('^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),

    # List post by tag
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),

    # Post
    url('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),

]
```

Comment: Thanks! However it yells again:
ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django.conf.urls'

Comment: Works like this.
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# App name
app_name = 'blog'

# Url Patterns
urlpatterns = [
    # Default lists all posts
    url('^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    
    # List post by tag
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
    
    # Post
    url('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),
    
]

Answer (score 0):

Works like this.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# App name
app_name = 'blog'

# Url Patterns
urlpatterns = [
    # Default lists all posts
    url('^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),

    # List post by tag
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),

    # Post
    url('(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
        views.post_detail,
        name='post_detail'),

]
```